# import another subpackage from a subpackage doesn't show docstirng in Pycharm

Tags: python, module, pycharm, package, relative-import

To make it simpler to understand, here is a minimal reproducible example.

Structure:

```
C:.
├───.idea
│   │   PyCharm stuff
└───src
    │   main.py
    │
    ├───folder
    │   │   script.py
    │   │   __init__.py
    │
    └───folder2
        │   script2.py
        │   __init__.py
```

I launch PyCharm in src, that's something I want.

My `main.py` code is the following:

```
from folder.script import my_function_script

if __name__ == '__main__':
    my_function_script()
```

This works very well. Autocomplete works and docstrings is available when hovering over the function names.
[image]

This is the module `script.py` from the package `folder`:

```
from folder2.script2 import my_function_script_2

def my_function_script() -> None:
    """
    This is a docstring
    :return: None
    """
    my_function_script_2()
```

Here is the problem. Because the IDE thinks I want to import the package `folder2` which is in `folder` nothing works (autocomplete, docstring, etc ...). But that's not the case since I know I only call `script.py` from `main.py` (which is not in the package `folder`). Hence why, I need to write from `folder2.script2` - otherwise if I call `script.py` from `main.py`, python won't find `folder2.script2`.

My question is then:

How do make it so that PyCharm understands that when I import stuff in the package `folder`, I do it by "being in `main.py`", therefore displaying the docstrings, checking the type of the variables if type hinting has been done, etc ...

Comment: Because the IDE thinks I want to import the package folder2 which is in folder nothing works -> folder2 is not in folder what do you mean?

Comment: I launch PyCharm in src -> that is also unclear, as seen from the docstring displayed src is the base package the working dir is c:

Comment: "I launch PyCharm in src -> that is also unclear" right click on folder that is parent to src, left click on open as pycharm project

Comment: folder2 is not in folder so the docstring doesn't appear but because i call the package folder from src and not from folder2 I don't go backwards when doing the relative import, which the IDE does not know. I'm trying to let the IDE know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After days of research, I found the answer.

Solution 1 :

Do `from src.folder2.script2` instead of `from folder2.script2` because I'm opening the project from the parent directory of `src`.

Solution 2 :

Set the source directory of the project as `src` as it currently is the parent directory of `src`.
[image]